# ng-repeat with two arrays of data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

updated. I have stored my data in an array of tuples: called $scope.unique.
basically it looks like this:

```
[["Chris Ivory", "Alfred Morris"], ["CJ", "DJAX"], ["DJ", "CX"]["Willie", "Fred]].
```

The tuple array can be of infinite length.  What I want to do is get the first two of each, then iterate up by two until I reach the end.

```
<div class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in unique" ($index + 2)>
                {{value[0]}} for {{value[1]}} 
            </div>
```

Comment: Show me your code first, please

Comment: just updated to include my code

Comment: I tried multiple options to come up with a way to create the output you are trying to reach, but I've come to the conclusion that you need to restructure your data in your JavaScript.  You can't change the way that `ng-repeat` iterates without writing a custom replacement for it, and if you try to limit what you show by using `ng-if` and `$index`, you will just end up with a large number of empty HTML elements.

Comment: @Claies, if he put ngIf on the repeated div it will be removed, but yes, this is still waste of time from ngRepeat (it will iterate and clone by unique.length) after ngIf will be compiled and remove the element, I agree that a custom directive should be good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making an array of tuples, I made an array of four values nested inside an outer array.

this is what worked:

```
<li style="list-style-type: none;">
                <div class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in unique">
                    {{value[0]}} and {{value[1]}} for {{value[2]}} and {{value[3]}}
                </div>

            </li>
```

Much Expected Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why you just don't do that ? :

JS:

```
    $scope.g1 = ["P1", "P2"];
    $scope.g2 = ["P3", "P4"];
    $scope.g = $scope.g1.concat($scope.g2);
```

HTML:

```
{{g[0]}} and {{g[1]}} against {{g[2]}} and {{g[4]}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
    <div ng-if="$index%2 == 0" class="text-center" ng-repeat="value in unique">
          {{value[0]}} for {{value[1]}} 
    </div>
```

[demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/3xOpwdP2T7R1d5xLPqjQ?p=preview)